# RaphaelJs Drag constraints

Tags: raphael, drag

I have a slider in which I want to be able to drag in the x-co ordinate only and and set constraints beyond which the shape cant be dragged (the shape shouldn't go beyond the line in both the directions). How can it be achieved?

JS Fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/4hASC/)

```
window.onload = function(){    

    var paper = Raphael(0,0,700,150);  

    var sliderline = paper.rect(68,100,606,1).attr({fill:'red',stroke:'none'});
    var slider = paper.rect(100,98,18,7,4).attr({fill:'#7cc576','stroke-width':'2','stroke':'white'}).glow({width:1,opacity:10,color:'green'});
}
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by assigning the handlers to the drag event. Inside the handler you can move the slider any way you wish.